# Fourier transform using propieties

Tags: fourier-transform

Hello :) I would like to ask you if the function $f(t)$ using this equivalence $f(w) = \frac{w_0}{(a+ jw)^2+ w_0^2}$ , can get a fourier transform ?

$f(t)$= $e^{-9t}$ $Sin(2t) H(t)$

and in that case could be this the result? $f(w) = \frac{2}{(9+ jw)^2+ 4}$ ?

Apologies if it's a silly question, but I just started Fourier transform :) 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to have already determined all you need to know to evaluate the inverse FT of $\frac{\omega_0}{\omega_0^2+(a+i\omega)^2}$

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear, I would like to know whether is  or is not correct to use that equivalence f (w) to be able to find the fourier transform for the function f (t) or am I skipping a step?

Comment: I believe you're correct. Your question is if $f(w)$ could be inverted to $f(x)$ when $f(w)$ is in certain form, right?

Comment: "Your question is if f(w) could be inverted to f(x) when f(w) is in certain form" , Yes, Poyea :)))